# how to skip test/scenarios at run time or while executing a specflow project

Tags: c#, specflow

Updated the question

I am using specflow .

I want to skip some scenario if they are not meeting specified conditions . these conditions can be different for each run.

I came across TestIgnore() from IUnitTestRuntimeProvider and some references for people using it in hooks [beforeScenaio]. I want to do the same but it is not working for me. Even after ignore code is executed , control goes to my scenario.
if I execute ignore code outside try catch block then it give me error
[image]

below is my code

```
public void Initialize() {
    tag = _testrailHelper.GetTestcaseId(_scenarioContext);
    if (resultstotr) {
        if (testTobeExecuted.Contains(TestCaseId))
        {
            //do something
        } else {
            IgnoreTest(_scenarioContext);
        }
```

And the IgnoreTest method:

```
public void IgnoreTest(ScenarioContext scenarioContext) {
    IUnitTestRuntimeProvider unitTestRuntimeProvider = (IUnitTestRuntimeProvider)scenarioContext.GetBindingInstance(typeof(IUnitTestRuntimeProvider));
    try {
        unitTestRuntimeProvider.TestIgnore("This scenario is ignored");
    } catch { }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "image of our code base"? Are you literally taking a screenshot of code? Please clarify your question, and include your own code trials.

Comment: See also [Run selected tests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/testing/selective-unit-tests?pivots=mstest), which describes how you can filter tests.

Comment: I am creating a docker image of my automation code base and then this image is used as a code source in my execution tool. In exec tool I give dotnet test  --filter <> and my test are executed .What I want to do is  this filter part should be taken care by my code so when I give dotnet test and use my docker image then required test should be executed

Comment: I am getting list of tests ( which is dynamic and can be different for every run) , in [Before Test] . I am looking to run the tests from the list only and ignore rest of them

Comment: It feels like you are fighting how these testing frameworks should be used. Typically you filter tests in the CI pipeline, using a task specialized in running tests.